# TCP Socket not receiving data, write/send does not timeout?

Tags: sockets, unix, solaris

I have have had made several projects and mock ups using TCP socket, but this is the first time I have encountered this.

I have a Linux server application on a solaris sparc machine that is supposed to accept a connection from an OCX on a webserver, but there is no data received. I used netstat to verify that the connection was established.

I created a tiny tcp client to connect to act as the web server/ocx, but what happens is at the write it stops there and a timeout never occurs. Even if I left the connection and the wait for a few hours, nothing happens. I have even gone as far as to use setsockopt to make sure a low timeout value is set. Also, on the other end, not data is received, and the select statement does timeout while polling the fd set.

Does anyone have an idea why write or send would not timeout while writing to a sokcet? Also, does anyone know why on the server, the read fd set was not set?

here is the dump from snoop:

```
solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35111 Fin Ack=1805515051 Seq=897643511 Len=0 Win=49640
10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35111 S=8882 Ack=897643512 Seq=1805515051 Len=0 Win=24818
solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35112 Syn Seq=921698308 Len=0 Win=49640 Options=<mss 1460,nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,sackOK>
10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35112 S=8882 Syn Ack=921698309 Seq=1829645518 Len=0 Win=24820 Options=<nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,sackOK,mss 1460>
solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35112 Ack=1829645519 Seq=921698309 Len=0 Win=49640
solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35112 Push Ack=1829645519 Seq=921698309 Len=2 Win=49640
10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35112 S=8882 Ack=921698311 Seq=1829645519 Len=0 Win=24818
```

using "snoop -x0 -s1500"

solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35291 Syn Seq=4205016629 Len=0 Win=49640 Options=

```
   0: 0800 20f5 a3b5 000c 295d 6f44 0800 4500    .. .....)]oD..E.
  16: 0034 e4c7 4000 4006 0000 0a01 003d 0a01    .4..@.@......=..
  32: 0025 89db 22b2 faa3 7635 0000 0000 8002    .%.."...v5......
  48: c1e8 148a 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0300 0101    .è..............
  64: 0402                                       ..
```

10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35291 S=8882 Syn Ack=4205016630 Seq=799808987 Len=0 Win=24820 Options=

```
   0: 000c 295d 6f44 0800 20f5 a3b5 0800 4500    ..)]oD.. .....E.
  16: 0034 c849 4000 4006 5e17 0a01 0025 0a01    .4.I@.@.^....%..
  32: 003d 22b2 89db 2fac 1ddb faa3 7636 8012    .=".../.....v6..
  48: 60f4 8ec1 0000 0103 0300 0101 0402 0204    `...............
  64: 05b4                                       ..
```

solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35291 Ack=799808988 Seq=4205016630 Len=0 Win=49640

```
   0: 0800 20f5 a3b5 000c 295d 6f44 0800 4500    .. .....)]oD..E.
  16: 0028 e4c8 4000 4006 0000 0a01 003d 0a01    .(..@.@......=..
  32: 0025 89db 22b2 faa3 7636 2fac 1ddc 5010    .%.."...v6/...P.
  48: c1e8 147e 0000                             .è.~..
```

solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35291 Push Ack=799808988 Seq=4205016630 Len=2 Win=49640

```
   0: 0800 20f5 a3b5 000c 295d 6f44 0800 4500    .. .....)]oD..E.
  16: 002a e4c9 4000 4006 0000 0a01 003d 0a01    .*..@.@......=..
  32: 0025 89db 22b2 faa3 7636 2fac 1ddc 5018    .%.."...v6/...P.
  48: c1e8 1480 0000 750a                        .è....u.
```

10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35291 S=8882 Ack=4205016632 Seq=799808988 Len=0 Win=24818

```
   0: 000c 295d 6f44 0800 20f5 a3b5 0800 4500    ..)]oD.. .....E.
  16: 0028 c84a 4000 4006 5e22 0a01 0025 0a01    .(.J@.@.^"...%..
  32: 003d 22b2 89db 2fac 1ddc faa3 7638 5010    .=".../.....v8P.
  48: 60f2 cf8c 0000 5555 5555 5555              `.....UUUUUU
```

solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35291 Fin Ack=799808988 Seq=4205016632 Len=0 Win=49640

```
   0: 0800 20f5 a3b5 000c 295d 6f44 0800 4500    .. .....)]oD..E.
  16: 0028 e4ca 4000 4006 0000 0a01 003d 0a01    .(..@.@......=..
  32: 0025 89db 22b2 faa3 7638 2fac 1ddc 5011    .%.."...v8/...P.
  48: c1e8 147e 0000                             .è.~..
```

10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35291 S=8882 Ack=4205016633 Seq=799808988 Len=0 Win=24818

```
   0: 000c 295d 6f44 0800 20f5 a3b5 0800 4500    ..)]oD.. .....E.
  16: 0028 c84b 4000 4006 5e21 0a01 0025 0a01    .(.K@.@.^!...%..
  32: 003d 22b2 89db 2fac 1ddc faa3 7639 5010    .=".../.....v9P.
  48: 60f2 cf8b 0000 5555 5555 5555              `.....UUUUUU
```

Comment: solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35111 Fin Ack=1805515051 Seq=897643511 Len=0 Win=49640

10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35111 S=8882 Ack=897643512 Seq=1805515051 Len=0 Win=24818
   
solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35112 Syn Seq=921698308 Len=0 Win=49640 Options=<mss 1460,nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,sackOK>

10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35112 S=8882 Syn Ack=921698309 Seq=1829645518 Len=0 Win=24820 Options=<nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,sackOK,mss 1460>

solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35112 Ack=1829645519 Seq=921698309 Len=0 Win=49640

Comment: solaris61 -> 10.1.0.37    TCP D=8882 S=35112 Push Ack=1829645519 Seq=921698309 Len=2 Win=49640

10.1.0.37 -> solaris61    TCP D=35112 S=8882 Ack=921698311 Seq=1829645519 Len=0 Win=24818

Comment: @marcus, you can edit the question itself, it'd be much more readable there.

Comment: @Nikolai, Silly me, I had copied it right out of a terminal without editing it first.

Comment: Handshake is fine, solaris61 sends 2 bytes to 10.1.0.37, which are acknowledged by the TCP stack. Can you check what has been send (ie. snoop into a file using the "-o filename" and "-s 1500" options)

Comment: Hi Icanhasserver, you got me a little lost there. Snoop -o filename -s 1500 produced a binary file. What am I supposed to be looking for here? And using the "-s" option, are you expecting the MTU is around 1500? Thanks

Comment: @marcus, use the `snoop`'s `-x0` option to display packet contents.

Comment: I used the -x0 option but the output was still a binary file. Do you think posting a octal using "od" version would be better?

Comment: No, use `-x0` without `-o` to display packet payload data in hex/ascii.

Comment: all right, posted the log again. 

The last logged packet should be the fifth packet, I just killed the program, that is why there aws an FIN and the final ACK. Otherwise, the dummy client stalls infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Get down to [`tcpdump(1)`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) and/or [`snoop(1M)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/snoop-1m.html#scrolltoc) to see what goes on on the wire on both sides. This is probably the best option for finding an explanation considering the "magic" you describe. Post more details as you find them.

Comment: from the connection of my dummy client to the part where it stalls, this is what snoop produced:

Answer (score 0):

You would only get a timeout if it was not getting back a TCP acknowledgment for something that was sent.  Your dump shows that all sent data was acknowledged, so no there should be no timeout.  The only data that was sent was 2 bytes from solaris61.

It sounds like you are saying that you intended to send some data TO solaris61.  This data was never sent.  How are you sending this data?  If you are writing using buffered stdio then the data may still be in the buffer.  For example if it is line buffered then it would be buffered until a newline is sent.  Instead you could turn off buffering using `setvbuf()` or just use `send()` to send the data directly.

(If you are already doing this then please post that part of the code.)

Comment: but then again, is it not that it will stay in buffer only for a few seconds at the most? I have tried letting it sit for a few hours actually, but nothing happend.

I could try to use send and recv, but the thing is I am doing this on a legacy system. So there would be a lot of points to change. Nonetheless, I will try your suggestion with using setvbuf.

Comment: You are thinking of the TCP buffers in the kernel.  Those buffers will be sent out automatically, but not stdio buffers.

Comment: I see your point. But I have been comparing the version I am working on with a much older version. And the old version worked fine. This is where using the dummy began. If this is the problem, then can't I just use something similar to a fflush()?

Comment: If you are in fact using stdio then `fflush()` would work also.

Comment: alright, there is a point to be clarified here. The problem is that the write() call does not return. with that, it is not possible to call anything else. So I think the unfilled buffer is the problem.